# Possible Memory Leak In Oracle.ManagedDataAccess Library

Tags: .net, oracle, memory, memory-leaks, oledb

I started writing a program that copies data from an oracle database to a SQL Server database and immediately ran into a memory issue.  I am using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library (nuget install command: "install-package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess").  The library is version 4.122.1.0

Here is my function:

```
    private static void LoadTable(TableToLoad table)
    {
        DataTable loadBuffer = null;
        //assume source is oracle for now.  assume destination is sql server
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(table.SourceConnectionString))
        {
            OracleDataReader reader = OracleCommands.GetDataReader(string.Format("select * from \"{0}\".\"{1}\"", table.SourceSchema, table.SourceTable),conn);
            bool foundData = reader.Read();
            if (loadBuffer == null)
            {
                loadBuffer = InitializeBuffer(reader);
            }

            int recordsAffected;

            while (foundData==true)
            {
                object[] currentRowValues = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                int valueCount = reader.GetValues(currentRowValues);
                loadBuffer.Rows.Add(currentRowValues);
                if (loadBuffer.Rows.Count >= 15000)
                {
                    SqlCommands.RunSqlCommandWithDataTableInput(string.Format("insert into {0}.{1} select * from @loadBufferTable", table.TargetSchema, table.TargetTable), table.TargetConnectionString, out recordsAffected, loadBuffer, "loadBufferTable");

                    loadBuffer.Dispose();
                    loadBuffer = null;
                    loadBuffer = InitializeBuffer(reader);
                }
                foundData = reader.Read();
            }

            if(loadBuffer.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                SqlCommands.RunSqlCommandWithDataTableInput(string.Format("insert into {0}.{1} select * from @loadBufferTable", table.TargetSchema, table.TargetTable), table.TargetConnectionString, out recordsAffected, loadBuffer, "loadBufferTable");

                loadBuffer.Dispose();
                loadBuffer = null;
            }

            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            reader = null;

        }
    }
```

When I run this the memory consumption just shoots up and in a few minutes I get an out of memory error.  I stopped the process and used the diagnostic tools to take a look at what was using so much memory.  Almost all the memory was taken up with tens of thousands of "OraBuf" objects which are created by the DataReader.Read method.
[image: Visual Studio Memory Usage Tool]

I tried deallocating and recreating the DataTable object I am using as a buffer for insert batch, thinking that maybe somehow the DataTable was holding onto a reference to the OraBuf objects but that did not fix the issue (I initially was using the DataTable.Clear() method to reset the DataTable).

Why is this happening (and what can I do to fix it)?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**
My test table in Oracle has a CLOB column in it.  The issue seems to be related to reading that CLOB value as the problem does not manifest when using other tables (no OutOfMemoryException).  Is there a better library for accessing Oracle that I should be using?

**EDIT 2:**
I should also mention that the table I am testing with (the one with the CLOB column) has about 2.9 million records and it usually fails somewhere between row 500,000 and row 1,500,000 (actual lowest row count before out of memory failure was about 649,000 and the highest was about 1,390,000).

**EDIT 3:**
I tried pairing down this code to help identify the problem and the one line that makes a difference is:

```
    int valueCount = reader.GetValues(currentRowValues);
```

I also tried a version where I only read one column at a time and in that case, reading the value using an index causes the problem (only on the CLOB column).  Here is the line in the alternate version that results in the exception:

```
    newRow[columnIndex] = reader[columnIndex];
```

Comment: Is this a one-time job? It yes, then perhaps you should consider another approach, e.g. DB-Link or transfer via CSV file.

Comment: Did you try `loadBuffer.Clear();` instead of disposing it?

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this.  I have tried loadBuffer.Clear() but that did not help.

Comment: It is a job we hope to run on a regular basis.  We have previously done our data syncing with SSIS packages (hundreds of them) but we are trying to build this solution which will be easier to use (when syncing a new table, we will just need to add it to sync list/table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with CLOB columns while reading 3 million rows in a batch application.When I set the InitialLobFetchSize to -1 it seems to keep the memory usage under control:

command.InitialLOBFetchSize = -1;

Comment: Thank you for answering this, I am sorry I haven't looked at it in so long.  We eventually addressed the issue by going back to an older OLEDB driver version (at the time the most recent 3 or 4 versions of the driver had this bug but there was a version before that which supported the database version and features we were using).  I am sorry I don't remember the exact version off the top of my head.  These fixes are great but the problem also manifested in other ways (in SSIS packages for example) so using the old driver was the best approach for us at the time.  Did Oracle ever fix this?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4119841) this is a LOB processing bug in the Oracle driver.

Workaround (taken from [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4119841)) is:

```
                    var dataValue = reader.GetOracleValue(i);  

                    if (dataValue != null)  
                    {  
                        // Test returned Type  
                        if (dataValue is OracleClob)  
                        {  
                            OracleClob oClob = dataValue as OracleClob;  
                            // Read text  
                            currentRowValues[i] = oClob.Value;  
                            oClob?.Close();  
                        }  
                        else if (dataValue is OracleBlob)  
                        {  
                            OracleBlob oBlob = dataValue as OracleBlob;  
                            // Read data  
                            currentRowValues[i] = oBlob.Value;  
                            oBlob?.Close();  
                        }  
                    }
```